# Google Guava and an error I can't figure out

Tags: java, guava

I get this error when trying to compile:

The method `filter(Iterable<T>, Predicate<? super T>)` in the type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (`Iterator<PeopleSoftBalance>, ColumnLikePredicate<PeopleSoftBalance>`)

Here is the ColumnLikePredicate class sig:

```
public class ColumnLikePredicate<T extends RowModel> implements Predicate<T>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to edit the question so that everybody can see. Remember this is a web page and greater than and less than symbols need to be escaped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you are passing an `Iterator` to a method that expects an `Iterable`.

[Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

> An iterator over a collection

[Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.

`Iterator` is an object that can be used to iterate over a (different) collection. `Iterable` is an object *that can be iterated over*.

I would guess that you have some sort of `collection` and you are calling something like `Iterables.filter(collection.iterator(), predicate)`. The `Iterables` class wants you to pass the Iterable itself, like:

```
Iterables.filter(collection, predicate)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that Guava includes both [Iterators.filter()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter%28java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) and [Iterables.filter()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) methods. Call the first method to filter an Iterator and the second method to filter an Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Does PeopleSoftBalance extend RowModel ?